# Strange black textures in paint

Tags: texturing

So I'm fairly certain this is an easy fix, but I'm creating a bastard sword, and when I started the texturing phase, there are very strange black textures that I can't paint over.
If you want to  help me with this issue, I would appreciate it so much.
I am very new to Blender, so sorry if this is a waste of your time.
Oh, and by the way, I am talking about on the handle, not the crossguard.

And I have more images if you need more info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are any of your UVs overlapping?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with all the terms, but I have deleted all doubles if that's what your asking, thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: Please upload your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2333" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2333/)

Comment: First I think you should look at the model's geometry. When I tried to use Remove Doubles, it deleted around 1500 vertices in each model. Also I can see you have some faces overlaying each others and there is a lot of unconnected geometry, so check / correct that too. Only then you will be able to do a proper texturing.

Comment: Is it because your Image Texture node isn't connected to the Diffuse node?

Comment: Sorry as I said before, I am very new at this. What part of the IT node and diffuse node should I connect?